# Weird Rendering HDR

Tags: rendering, hdri

I am currently using an HDR for the first time in blender ( I am quite new).
When I render the image, I get some strange artifacts in silver materials and I additionally have small squares (as big as the tile size) which render incorrect. They are much brighter than the rest of the scene.
And they are always on the same position, even if I rotate the HDR.
I have downloaded my HDRs from hdrihaven. And when I change to an different HDR the parts which are not correct are mostly the same.
Has anyone else had this problem or has a solution? :)

[image: HDR]

Comment: Are you GPU rendering? I suspect faulty graphics card

Comment: Yes I am rendering on an Nvidia RTX 2080 Super and an GTX 1050. Before I used an studio HDR and didn't have that issue. I now tried several HDRs and it's always the same issue.

Comment: I now tried rendering on CPU (no issue), only 1050 (no issue) and only 2080 (no issue). Is it because I use 2 graphics cards which are not the exact same model? And thank you for your tip with the graphics card. I think I would have never considered that it's the graphics card without your tip :)

Comment: Heterogeneous setups should in theory be supported, in practice there may be occasional issues as you are experiencing

Comment: It's the gpu differences you can have two different instances rendering different frames on either gpu.